# Laravel TCPDF alternative for PHP 7

Tags: php, laravel

I have an old project based on Laravel which used PHP 5.4. but now on updating to PHP 7 I get this error.

How can I solve this?

```
PHP Deprecated:  The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /home/prescri1/sub_domains/sign.prescripz.com/src/TCPDF/tcpdi.php on line 629
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes laravel have TCPD alternative you can use it mPDF

https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf